# How to save order of the stream in map

Tags: java, java-stream

I try to get order map from stream. I have next code:

```
Map<String, PatternWrapper> regexps = allConfigurations
    .stream()
    .flatMap(configuration -> configuration.getPlugins().stream())
    .sorted(
            (left, right) -> {
                if (left.getType().equals(ObfuscationType.REGEX_BLACKLIST) &&
                        right.getType().equals(ObfuscationType.REGEX_BLACKLIST))
                    return 0;
                else if (left.getType().equals(ObfuscationType.REGEX_BLACKLIST) &&
                        (!right.getType().equals(ObfuscationType.REGEX_BLACKLIST)))
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
    )
//    .sorted(LogConfiguration.Plugin::compareTo)
    .filter(plugin -> (ObfuscationType.REGEX.equals(plugin.getType())
            || ObfuscationType.REGEX_BLACKLIST.equals(plugin.getType())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            plugin -> plugin.getId(),
            plugin -> new
                    PatternWrapper(plugin.getId(), Pattern.
                    compile(plugin.getValue()))));

return regexps;
```

Where I try order a stream of the data and I think that map also was ordered. But I was wrong. I think that call collect(Collectors.toMap()) don't save order of the stream. Are there example how I can do that?

Comment: You could change the `Map` to something like a `TreeMap` which has ordering. You could define your own ordering based on your keys (or use the natural ordering of `String`).

Comment: @tobias_k sorted doesn't mean ordered

Comment: @Nick do you understand why a hashmap has no ordering? (which is the default map that is used in the `Collectors.toMap()`)

Comment: As a side note, you can simplify your code significantly by using `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(element -> element.getType().equals(ObfuscationType.REGEX_BLACKLIST)));`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `allConfigurations.stream` maintains order as you have told...

You can use the overload of `Collectors.toMap` that takes a `mapSupplier` and hence you can pass a `LinkedHashMap` since that maintains insertion order.

```
Collectors.toMap(
        plugin -> plugin.getId(),
        plugin -> new
                PatternWrapper(plugin.getId(), Pattern.
                compile(plugin.getValue())),
        (left, right) -> left,
        LinkedHashMap::new);
```

The third parameter here is a merge function that is used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key. But that shouldn't be an issue here as you didn't have one in your original code.

Comment: @Nick Then you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, to show others that your question has been answered to your satisfaction, and to award rep to user7 for providing the answer.

Comment: yes, i trying do it at a work, but get alert that i should wait 3 minutes.